# scipy.optimize.curve_fit run in Java using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, python, scipy

I am running a curve fitting Python script in Java using Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec and Java is not getting output after one of my calls to scipy.optimize.curve_fit. 
I am fitting to a piecewise error function as shown below.

I created a "dummy" version of the function to check that the curve fitting would work on that, and it did. But when I apply the curve fit to actual data, Java does not get any of the output below that statement.

I ran the Python code in the terminal and it worked fine.

Java code:

```
String[] command = new String[2];
command[0] = "python";
command[1] = "python/curvefit.py";


try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((s1 = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Python code

```
## modifiable error function
def easyerf(x,a,b,c, d):
    return a*scipy.special.erf((b * x) - c) + d

## piecewise error function
def pwerf(x, a1, a2, b, c1, c2, h, e):
    returnarray = []
    for i in x:
        if i < e:
            returnarray.append(easyerf(i, a1, b, c1, h - a1))
        else:
            returnarray.append(easyerf(i, a2, b, c2, h + a2))
    return returnarray


array = np.linspace(-5, 10, 15)
array2 = np.linspace(10, 25, 15)
array3 = [easyerf(i, 4, 1, 1, 1) for i in array]
array4 = [easyerf(i, -4, 1, 15, 1) for i in array2]
array5 = np.concatenate((array,array2)) # x values
array6 = np.concatenate((array3,array4)) # y values
pguess7 = [10, -4, 17, 1, 15, 1, 10]

par3, con3 = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(pwerf, array5, array6, p0 = pguess7)

print("got here")

indexes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,... ## long array
intensities = [0.050938000000000004, 0.049611, 0.054938, 0.047958,... ## long array

## fit piecewise error function and find ends/length
par4, con4 = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(pwerf, indexes, intensities, [10, 1, 1, 5, 17, 25,120])
print("now got here")
```

Java prints only the first "got here" but not the "now got here" that should follow after the second curve fit. Again, it works perfectly fine in the terminal. I need to get the output from the second curve fit. What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Figured it out. Java is running an older version of Python and requires the arguments of curve_fit to be numpy arrays, not lists.